# Date is not displayed correctly when plot pandas dataframe

Tags: matplotlib, dataframe, pandas

first, if I use DataReader to read in the data, and then plot, everything is good

```
In [55]: t = DataReader('SPY','yahoo', start=datetime.datetime(1990,1,1))

In [56]: t
Out[56]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 5033 entries, 1993-01-29 00:00:00 to 2013-01-23 00:00:00
Data columns:
Open         5033  non-null values
High         5033  non-null values
Low          5033  non-null values
Close        5033  non-null values
Volume       5033  non-null values
Adj Close    5033  non-null values
dtypes: float64(5), int64(1)

In [58]: t.plot()
Out[58]: <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0x8cca790>
```

However, if I save it as a csv file and reload it again, I got error message and the plot is not quite right either,

```
In [62]: t.to_csv('spy.csv')

In [63]: s = pd.read_csv('spy.csv', na_values=[" "])

In [64]: s.set_index('Date')
Out[64]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 5033 entries, 1993-01-29 00:00:00 to 2013-01-23 00:00:00
Data columns:
Open         5033  non-null values
High         5033  non-null values
Low          5033  non-null values
Close        5033  non-null values
Volume       5033  non-null values
Adj Close    5033  non-null values
dtypes: float64(5), int64(1)

In [66]: s.plot()                                                            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) 
/home/dli/pythonTest/pandas/<ipython-input-66-d3eb09d34df4> in <module>()   
----> 1 s.plot()                                                            

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/core/frame.pyc in plot(self, subplots, sharex, sharey, use_index, figsize, grid, legend, rot, ax, kind, **kwds)
3748                     ax.legend(loc='best')                              
3749                 else:                                                  
-> 3750                     ax.plot(x, y, label=str(col), **kwds)           
3751                                                                        
3752                 ax.grid(grid)                                          

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.pyc in plot(self, *args, **kwargs)
3891         lines = []                                                     
3892                                                                        
-> 3893         for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):               
3894             self.add_line(line)                                        
3895             lines.append(line)                                         

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.pyc in _grab_next_args(self, *args, **kwargs)
    320                 return                                              
    321             if len(remaining) <= 3:                                 
--> 322                 for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):      
    323                     yield seg                                       
    324                 return                                              

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.pyc in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    279         ret = []                                                    
    280         if len(tup) > 1 and is_string_like(tup[-1]):                
--> 281             linestyle, marker, color = _process_plot_format(tup[-1])
    282             tup = tup[:-1]                                          
    283         elif len(tup) == 3:                                         

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.pyc in _process_plot_format(fmt)
    93     # handle the multi char special cases and strip them from the    

    94     # string                                                         

---> 95     if fmt.find('--')>=0:                                           
    96         linestyle = '--'                                             
    97         fmt = fmt.replace('--', '')                                  

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks.
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) method *returns* a new DataFrame by default, rather than applying this inplace (in fact, most pandas functions are similar). It has an `inplace` argument:

```
s.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
s.plot()
```

*which works as you intended!*

Note: to convert the Index to a DatetimeIndex you can use `to_datetime`:

```
s.index = s.index.to_datetime()
```

.

Which is to say, `s` remained unchanged by you `.set_index('Date')`:

```
In [63]: s = pd.read_csv('spy.csv', na_values=[" "])

In [64]: s.set_index('Date')
Out[64]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 5033 entries, 1993-01-29 00:00:00 to 2013-01-23 00:00:00
Data columns:
Open         5033  non-null values
High         5033  non-null values
Low          5033  non-null values
Close        5033  non-null values
Volume       5033  non-null values
Adj Close    5033  non-null values
dtypes: float64(5), int64(1)

In [65]: s
Out[65]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5033 entries, 0 to 5032
Data columns:
Date         5033  non-null values
Open         5033  non-null values
High         5033  non-null values
Low          5033  non-null values
Close        5033  non-null values
Volume       5033  non-null values
Adj Close    5033  non-null values
dtypes: float64(5), int64(1), object(1)
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, However, after I use inplace=True, I got the following error "ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2013-01-23 00:00:00"

Comment: @user1591487 What version of pandas are you using? (It works fine on my machine...)

Comment: Time to upgrade! I'd not recommend to use anythin below 0.81 (shipped with current debian-based distributions), 0.10.1 is current stable (I think) and there is 0.11 available as "in development"

Comment: After I upgrade to 0.10.0, it works, but not perfectly, in the original dataframe t, the index is "DatetimeIndex", but in the new dataframe s, the index is just "Index", so when it plot, it doesn't treat it as datetime. so my next question is how do I make it "DatetimeIndex"?

Comment: @user1591487 `s.index = s.index.to_datetime()` :)